# Adding Subscribers in all subscriber list but they are not searchable

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

I am trying to add subscribers lists. I have imported them about 20 k records.

When I check the number of records, It provides the correct number. It still shows the wrong list size (244)
[image]

When I try to query a record I know to be there, it doesnt find it.[image][image]

Would appreciate help in resolving this

Comment: The email address you are showing in your search is invalid - notice the 'Dustin' after the '.com'.  This will cause SFMC to view it as invalid and not import it.  Check the email notification that you receive when importing files to see if it is similar validation issues that is reducing the number of subscribers imported.

Comment: It's a typo. That's the subscriber key and I searched with subscriber key